# Webpack Encore average compile time goes down from 160ms to 270ms after adding Bootstrap

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4, webpack-encore

When I add bootstrap in my app.scss file via `@import` my dev-compilation time goes down from **~160ms** to **~270ms** even though I didn't change anything in the bootstrap file (I made changes on a small other.scss file).

Is this a normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong? I assumed, once the bootstrap file was compiled, it would be cached in the dev-environment!?